# SQL Server installation error with Window 11

Tags: sql-server, window

While installing SQL Server 2016 or 2019 express edition in my Window 11 Laptop its throwing error. All the services are installed but SQL server DB instances are not running. [image]  Its showing following error by seeing this I'm not able to figure out what is the issue with installation.

Some where I read with Win11 in SSD drive SQL server is not installing. Any technical reason of it.

Comment: Have you tried opening the log file mentioned in your screen shot and looking at the error message(s)? SQL Server is known to have issues installing onto media that misreport their sector sizes, or those that report sector sizes greater than 4 kiB.

Comment: No response from op, I still think it's related to this: [Troubleshoot errors related to system disk sector size greater than 4 KB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/troubleshoot-os-4kb-disk-sector-size).

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning for your suggestion. Can you please point me which log file I need to look upon. Will try again deleting all SQL instances and will try to set it up again.

Comment: The screen shot in your quesiton includes the folder path that's containing the Setup Log file(s). But in relation to the troubleshooting link above you're probably looking for the SQL Server instance's `ERRORLOG` file and the path for that should be visible via SQL Server 2019 Configuration Manager > SQL Server Services > SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) > Properties > Startup Parameters, in particular the `-e` parameter in the list of parameters there.